# *DOM* Multiple forms should be contained in their own form elements

Tags: dom, google-chrome-devtools

On Google Chrome Console, I gets below yellow warning.I added the marked html code to below.What is the problem with this code? How can I solve it?

```
[DOM] Multiple forms should be contained in their own form elements; break up complex forms into ones that represent a single action:
```

(More info: 
https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/create-amazing-password-forms
 )

---

```
<form method="post" class="register" data-enable-strength-password="" data-minimum-password-strength="" novalidate="novalidate">

    <div class="ur-form-row">
        <div class="ur-form-grid ur-grid-1" style="width:48%">
            <div class="ur-field-item field-user_login">
                <div class="form-row validate-required" id="user_login_field" data-priority=""><label for="user_login" class="ur-label">Username <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label><input data-rules="" data-id="user_login" type="text" class="input-text input-text ur-frontend-field " name="user_login" id="user_login" placeholder="" value="" required="required" data-label="Username"></div>                                                          </div>
            <div class="ur-field-item field-user_pass">
                <div class="form-row validate-required hide_show_password" id="user_pass_field" data-priority=""><label for="user_pass" class="ur-label">User Password <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label><span class="password-input-group"><input data-rules="" data-id="user_pass" type="password" class="input-text input-password ur-frontend-field " name="user_pass" id="user_pass" placeholder="" value="" required="required" data-label="User Password"></span></div>                                                            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ur-form-grid ur-grid-2" style="width:48%">
            <div class="ur-field-item field-user_email">
                <div class="form-row validate-required" id="user_email_field" data-priority=""><label for="user_email" class="ur-label">User Email <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label><input data-rules="" data-id="user_email" type="email" class="input-text input-email ur-frontend-field " name="user_email" id="user_email" placeholder="" value="" required="required" data-label="User Email"></div>                                                            </div>
            <div class="ur-field-item field-user_confirm_password">
                <div class="form-row validate-required hide_show_password" id="user_confirm_password_field" data-priority=""><label for="user_confirm_password" class="ur-label">Confirm Password <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label><span class="password-input-group"><input data-rules="" data-id="user_confirm_password" type="password" class="input-text input-password ur-frontend-field " name="user_confirm_password" id="user_confirm_password" placeholder="" value="" required="required" data-label="Confirm Password"></span></div>                                                          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ur-button-container ">

        <button type="submit" class="btn button ur-submit-button ">
            <span></span>
            Submit                      </button>

    </div>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="ur-user-form-id" value="439">
    <input type="hidden" name="ur-redirect-url" value="">
    <input type="hidden" id="ur_frontend_form_nonce" name="ur_frontend_form_nonce" value="a5b1afe3f9">
</form>
```

Comment: This is because you have several `type=password` inside one form ([source code](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:components/autofill/content/renderer/page_passwords_analyser.cc;l=143)).

Comment: It's another step away from monopoly Chrome, how to throw sticks at developers' feet. This is because Chrome doesn't follow the autocomplete = off standard and developers try to work around it, so Chrome uses this method to make developers stupid.